# Fade in out bootstrap slider

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, slider, fadeout

I am trying to make my bootstrap slider fade in out when changing slides as in 
[this template.](http://www.bootply.com/86170#). I am using visual 2010 with asp.net. Now the problem is that when image changes it won't change slightly, a gray background appears for a less then one second before the second image appears. I really cannot now what's happening here... I am using bootstrap 3.3.7 and below is my code:

```
<style type="text/css">
.carousel-fade .carousel-inner .item {
              opacity: 0;
              -webkit-transition-property: opacity;
              -moz-transition-property: opacity;
              -o-transition-property: opacity;
              transition-property: opacity;
            }
            .carousel-fade .carousel-inner .active {
                opacity: 1;
            }
            .carousel-fade .carousel-inner .active.left,
            .carousel-fade .carousel-inner .active.right {
              left: 0;
              opacity: 0;
              z-index: 1;
            }
            .carousel-fade .carousel-inner .next.left,
            .carousel-fade .carousel-inner .prev.right {
              opacity: 1;
            }
            .carousel-fade .carousel-control {
              z-index: 2;
            }     
  </style>   
</head>
<body>
<div id="Carousel" class="carousel slide carousel-fade">
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            <li data-target="Carousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
            <li data-target="Carousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
            <li data-target="Carousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
        </ol>

        <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="item active">
                <img src="../Images/ImageE_Beta.jpg" class="img-responsive"/>
            </div>
           <div class="item">
             <img src="../Images/ImageE_Beta.jpg" class="img-responsive"/>
            </div>
           <div class="item">
             <img src="../Images/ImageE_Beta.jpg" class="img-responsive"/>
            </div>
        </div>

        <a class="left carousel-control" href="#Carousel" data-slide="prev">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
        </a>
        <a class="right carousel-control" href="#Carousel" data-slide="next">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
        </a>
</div>
</body>
```

Any hints?

**Update**

Now I have changed `<div id="Carousel" class="carousel slide carousel-fade">` to 
`<div id="Carousel" style="background-color:red" class="carousel slide carousel-fade">` and the color that appears between two images when they are changed is red.

Comment: You only specified the transition-property here - what about the other parameters, such as the transition-duration ...? The initial value for duration is `0s`, and that might be a bit short for your eyes to actually see something happening ...

Comment: @CBroe my thoughts exactly

Comment: Because the transition duration is setted in bootstrap css library in  .carousel-inner > .item and it's value is equal to 0.6s (which I have changed to 1.5s). But in both cases when fading: there is a gray background that appears between two images. Like if it is fading incorrectly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I could resolve the problem by removing the block: `@media all and (transform-3d), (-webkit-transform-3d)` that is specific for carousel-inner.

Comment: nice solution. I really wanted to know what was the problem

Answer (score 1):

My hint would be to use the "transition-duration" tag and so on. u should read some pages on how to create sliders there are enough of them.

But really my hint would be to set the transition duration at least on something becouse now its the standard 0 seconds.

another few reasons this may not work:

you have `style` tags but do u even load in the bootstrap? there is no "style include".

Or maybe this is outdated. u can see that the uploader of the slider has been downvoted so it may not work

Hope this helps.

Comment: Check my comment above please !

Comment: And why it should work in the template and not in my project ?!

Comment: tested the code it does not work for me to so it may be outdated.

Comment: no problem further im out of the blue on this one. upvoted your post and i will bookmark. im interested in why this does not work

Comment: Well the only difference between my project and the template was the bootstrap version: I am using version 3.3.7 and in the template they are using 3.0.0. So when I downloaded the old one : it worked like a shine...

Comment: well technically i said that already. that it may be outdated. so it turned out the bootstrap was outdated? but at least nice it worked.